# jQuery if object has value

Tags: jquery, object

I have an object built up like so:

```
tabArray.push({'linkId': 'tabBuild', 'id': 'columnRight','url': '/pages/publish/', 'content':response});
```

How can i use jQuery/javascript to do a test on that object to see if it contains a certain URL?

I tried this: `if($.inArray('/pages/publish/', tabArray) > -1) alert('its in there');`

But to no avail!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find object by id in array of javascript objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364150/find-object-by-id-in-array-of-javascript-objects)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
var inArray = false;
for (var i = 0; i < tabArray.length; i++) {
  if (tabArray[i].url === '/pages/publish') {
    inArray = true;
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Careful accessing .url on every element of the array like this, it might not always be defined.

Comment: @Skylar if it's not defined then it should returned `undefined` and fail the comparison with the string literal. I don't see how this will cause a problem.

Comment: It's OK if `url` is not defined. Accessing it in this way will return `undefined`, which is not `===` to `'/pages/publish'`, and the code will continue on its merry way.

Comment: You guys are right, I guess I was speaking more to my own coding style rather than what is necessarily syntactically sound. Good catch.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
var inArray = !!$.grep(tabArray, function(item) {
        return item.url === '/pages/publish/';
    }).length;

console.log(inArray); // true
```

Comment: Thanks. Should probably also be a -1 for not short-circuiting once a match is found, but iterations are fast and I *usually* go for readability if the performance tradeoff is minimal.

Answer (score 0):

$.inArray won't work as it is only meant to search an array of strings while your array is an array of objects.  You can create your own in array method.

```
var inURLArray = function(url, array) {
  for(var i in array) {
    if(array[i].url && array[i].url === url)
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `==` here instead of `===`?  I don't believe the `array[i].url &&` portion is necessary.  If `array[i].url` isn't defined then it will return `undefined` and fail the comparison with `url`